# Print two columns array into HTML table

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I have the following Query that I have to display in a HTML table:

```
$query= "SELECT SUM(amount_pln) AS suma,country FROM fin_revenues GROUP BY country ORDER BY suma DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
```

When running the query in PHPMYADMIN, it works perfectly as I need   but I can't figure out how to get the same result on a html table.

That's how is displayed in phpmyadmin:

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $query= "SELECT SUM(amount_pln) AS suma,country FROM fin_revenues GROUP BY country ORDER BY suma DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);

    echo "<table><tr><td>SUMA</td><td>country</td></tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['suma']."</td><td>".$row['country']."</td></tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Comment: Thanks, so far I get only the titles SUMA & country

Comment: @user2952715, I've updated my answer.. Is there any error you getting?

Comment: Both the answer looks similar, if your answer was first and correct than why other people post same answer again. up vote from my side for your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$query= "SELECT SUM(amount_pln) AS suma,country FROM fin_revenues GROUP BY country ORDER BY suma DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
echo '<table>
        <tr>
          <td>Suma</td>
          <td>Country></td>
       </tr>';
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($mysqli,$result))   // while there are records
{
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['suma']."</td><td>".$row['country']."</td></tr>";   // echo the table with query results
}
echo '</table';
```

Comment: I get an error in the following line, seems because of the single quotes
echo "<tr><td>$row['suma']</td><td>$row['country']</td></tr>";